# How can we connect ActiveMQ and WebSphere MQ in one Spring Boot application?

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms, amq

In Spring Boot 2.6.11 application  we are trying to consume data from ActiveMQ and publish data to WebSphere MQ.

For that if we need to manual configure both the ActiveMQ and WebSphere MQ?
If yes then how?
I am using below ActiveMQ config:

```java
@Bean
public Queue producerQueue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue(PRODUCER_QUEUE);
}

@Bean
public Queue consumerQueue() {
    return new ActiveMQQueue(CONSUMER_QUEUE);
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(BROKER_URL);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setPassword(BROKER_PASSWORD);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setUserName(BROKER_USERNAME);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    return new JmsTemplate(activeMQConnectionFactory());
}
```

How can I configure WebSphere MQ in the same application? I have added below dependency for WebSphere MQ:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.4</version>
</dependency>      
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
   <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

wmq properties

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=XXX
ibm.mq.channel=XXX
ibm.mq.connName=XXX
ibm.mq.connPort=XXX
ibm.mq.queueName=XXX
ibm.mq.user=XXX
ibm.mq.password=XXX
```

I am getting one bean of `JmsTemplate` which is connecting to ActiveMQ only. How can I create `JmsTemplate` bean for WebSphere MQ to publish the data?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem, and why did it fail?

Comment: Is the code on github: https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS/tree/master helpful?  This is camel code, but shows both IBM MQ and ActiveMQ useage.  The pom.xml files should be helpful.  Also note that these examples are transactional (DUPS-OK).  You should be able to combine these to meet your needs.